# vue-jest configuration - Is there a way to map aliases that occur in template/script src attributes?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, jestjs, vue-jest

Dependencies: "@vue/cli-plugin-unit-jest": "^4.5.13", "@vue/test-utils": "^1.2.1", "vue-jest": "^3.0.7"

I have an app which uses an alias (say "foo") being set in vue.config.js:

```
module.exports = {
  chainWebpack: (config) => {
    // Add project name as alias
    config.resolve.alias.set('foo', __dirname);
  },
};
```

For both import statements and HTML tag src...

In main.js:

```
...
import App from 'foo/src/components/core/App';
...
```

In ../src/core/App/index.vue:

```html
<script src="foo/src/components/core/App/script.js" />
<style module src="foo/src/components/core/App/style.css" />
<template src="foo/src/components/core/App/template.html" />
```

I know I can use a moduleNameMapper in jest.config.js, something like:

`'^foo(.*)$': '<rootDir>$1',`

However, this doesn't map aliases that appear in the src attribute of my HTML tags. Is there any way to have vue-jest interpret these attribute paths via a config setting or some other means?

Any recommendations will be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

### URL parsing in SFCs

`vue-jest` doesn't resolve `src` URLs for the top-level block tags in SFCs, so you'll have to use un-aliased relative paths in `src/components/core/App/index.vue`:

```html
<script src="./script.js" />
<style module src="./style.css" />
<template src="./template.html" />
```

### URL parsing in `<template>` contents

`vue-jest` uses `@vue/component-compiler-utils` to compile the template, but URL parsing requires the [`transformAssetUrls` option](https://github.com/vuejs/component-compiler-utils/blob/47f1341/README.md#compiletemplatetemplatecompileoptions-templatecompileresults). `vue-jest` 3.x does not support passing options to `@vue/component-compiler-utils`, but that now works in [4.0.0-rc.1](https://github.com/vuejs/vue-jest/releases/tag/v4.0.0-rc.1) via a [`templateCompiler.transformAssetUrls` config](https://github.com/vuejs/vue-jest#templatecompiler).

Even with this URL parsing enabled, Vue CLI configures `jest` to [return an empty string for `require`-ed media, including images](https://github.com/vuejs/vue-cli/blob/882aaca/packages/%40vue/cli-plugin-unit-jest/presets/default/jest-preset.js#L19-L20). If your tests need to work with the normally resolved URLs in production, you'll need a Jest transform that mimics [`url-loader`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/url-loader). Vue CLI configures the loader to [return the resolved filename if greater than 4KB; or the base64 data URL otherwise](https://github.com/vuejs/vue-cli/blob/dev/packages/%40vue/cli-service/lib/config/assets.js#L23).

*To enable the URL parsing:*

1. Update to `vue-jest` 4:

   ```sh
   npm i -D vue-jest@4
   ```
2. Create the following file for the custom `my-jest-url-loader`, which we'll use later below:

   ```js
   // <rootDir>/tests/my-jest-url-loader.js
   const urlLoader = require('url-loader')

   module.exports = {
     process(src, filename) {
       const urlLoaderOptions = {
         esModule: false,
         limit: 4096,
         fallback: {
           loader: 'file-loader',
           options: {
             esModule: false,
             emitFile: false,
             name: filename,
           },
         },
       }
       const results = urlLoader.call({
         query: urlLoaderOptions,
         resourcePath: filename,
       }, src)

       // strip leading Webpack prefix from file path if it exists
       return results.replace(/^module.exports = __webpack_public_path__ \+ /, 'module.exports = ')
     }
   }
   ```
3. To avoid accidentally overwriting Vue CLI's default Jest presets, use a merge utility (e.g., [`lodash.merge`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/lodash.merge)) to insert a custom config in `jest.config.js`.
4. Add a `vue-jest` config in a [Jest global](https://jestjs.io/docs/configuration#globals-object), setting [`templateCompiler.transformAssetUrls`](https://github.com/vuejs/vue-jest#templatecompiler).
5. Modify the merged preset's `transform` property to use our `my-jest-url-loader` transform for images. This requires removing other image transforms from the default Jest preset to avoid conflicts.

   ```js
   // jest.config.js
   const vueJestPreset = require('@vue/cli-plugin-unit-jest/presets/default/jest-preset')
   const merge = require('lodash.merge') 3️⃣

   const newJestPreset = merge(vueJestPreset, {
     globals: { 4️⃣
       'vue-jest': {
         templateCompiler: {
           transformAssetUrls: {
             video: ['src', 'poster'],
             source: 'src',
             img: 'src',
             image: ['xlink:href', 'href'],
             use: ['xlink:href', 'href']
           }
         }
       }
     },
     moduleNameMapper: {
       '^foo/(.*)$': '<rootDir>/$1',
     },
   })

   function useUrlLoaderForImages(preset) { 5️⃣
     const imageTypes = ['jpg', 'jpeg', 'png', 'svg', 'gif', 'webp']
     const imageTypesRegex = new RegExp(`(${imageTypes.join('|')})\\|?`, 'ig')

     // remove the image types from the transforms
     Object.entries(preset.transform).filter(([key]) => {
       const regex = new RegExp(key)
       return imageTypes.some(ext => regex.test(`filename.${ext}`))
     }).forEach(([key, value]) => {
       delete preset.transform[key]
       const newKey = key.replace(imageTypesRegex, '')
       preset.transform[newKey] = value
     })

     preset.transform = {
       ...preset.transform,
       [`.+\\.(${imageTypes.join('|')})$`]: '<rootDir>/tests/my-jest-url-loader',
     }
   }

   useUrlLoaderForImages(newJestPreset)

   module.exports = newJestPreset
   ```

[GitHub demo](https://github.com/tony19-contrib/vue-jest-asset-url-transforms)